# What are the security implications of not hosting your own Electrum server?

Tags: electrum

Bitcoin-Qt is getting require large and is taking up over 10% of the space on my little laptop. Looking for an alternative, I saw [Electrum](http://electrum.org/). I downloaded the app and I'm able to connect to a server, but I'm wondering: **what would the security implications be of not connecting to your own server**?

Comment: I like to know what are the security implication of *hosting your own server* :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good follow up question. You should ask it, and link it here!

Comment: good idea, done:  [Vice Versa](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/what-are-the-security-consideration-for-hosting-your-own-electrum-server)

Comment: @barrymac Nothing, unless there's a security issue in Electrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dishonest server could lie to you about how many bitcoins you have.

Comment: Don't all the Electrum servers connect to each other, so you can connect to any of them? If so, wouldn't they all hold the same information about your account?

Comment: All of the honest servers will tell you the same thing. But a dishonest server could lie.

Comment: This is not correct, they can give you false *low* wallet balances, but not falsely high ones.

Comment: @bitcoin sure it could - by not telling you about a transaction that spends one of your outputs.

Comment: @NickODell are you sure about this? what you describe would be a client that fully trusts the server, however according to this talk from the author of Electrum (https://youtu.be/hjYCXOyDy7Y?t=718 <- exact moment) it says that Electrum is one level above the "server-trusting" wallets, that is, it's a SPV wallet; if this is still the case nowadays, I wonder what's the difference between this and a "server-trusting" wallet?

Comment: @user1623521 He describes what he means in that video. To rephrase what he said, Electrum servers tell a client, "You got this transaction and this transaction and this transaction." Servers for server-trusting wallets say, "You have five bitcoins, trust me, I added it up correctly." In other words, 'server trusting wallets' can hide *or exaggerate* your Bitcoin holdings.

Comment: @NickODell you didn't seem to watch the video I sent; Electrum does some validation on the messages it gets from the servers to make sure they are not lying

Answer (score 2):

They'll be able to track your transactions/addresses and tie them to your IP address, although this is mitigated if you are using proxies (you can also go through Tor).