# Is there a tutorial on how to set up a secure enviroment and use Electrum?

Tags: wallet, security, electrum

Which OS to use? How to verify that the OS is secure?

How to download and install Electrum securely? There are many methods - binaries, git, homebrew, Ubuntu package, building from source.

Is there a tutorial that has step by step instructions on how to set up a secure environment for Electrum and use it securely?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/what-are-the-security-considerations-for-hosting-your-own-electrum-server says since there is no private information they couldn't do much if it was insecure.

Comment: Also if security is your aim then Ubuntu (and Linux in general) is a bad choice as they aren't particularly secure compared to proper Unix (like a Solaris or a BSD derivative.)  If you must use Linux then you should look to a hardened version like RHEL or CentOS.

Answer (score -2):

Here is check http://secure-bitcoin.blogspot.ru/, please leave a comment if you find any mistakes